# New function to SharePoint Rest API

Tags: sharepoint

I want to add new function to SharePoint Rest API services.

How can I create new SharePoint REST new  endpoint ?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Read [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/how-to-ask) before asking.

Comment: I am not asking to write code. I need a way @SteveFest

Comment: Have you Google'd up? A simple search `sharepoint REST API function` should get what you want.

Comment: And your question does not match your post body! Do you want to make a `function` or an `endpoint`?

Comment: I tried it. It is giving me original API services info to use the endpoints. But ı want to create new one. @SteveFest

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-service-endpoint-in-configuration)?

Comment: In the end, you are writing one function and you will access that one with endpoint right ? @SteveFest

Comment: I do not know Sharepoint very well. How about [this?](https://www.google.com.us/search?rlz=1C1CHZL_zh-TWHK745HK745&q=sharepoint+create+endpoint+and+function&oq=sharepoint+create+endpoint+and+function&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160k1.48279.49560.0.49790.13.12.0.0.0.0.123.1109.6j5.11.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.9.919...33i21k1.nQuZQPpgVUs)

Comment: thanx for sending link.But that was normal WCF config. I need SharePoint custom endpoint config setting.. @SteveFest

Comment: [Here on MSDN - Custom configurations in custom endpoints](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5e6ec5aa-98d5-4979-85bd-279412f54ea9/how-to-configure-service-endpoints-of-custom-webservice-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Comment: I will read and try the last link which you send. Thanks @SteveFest